# Passing all parameters to a function in fish shell

Tags: bash, function, shell, fish

Just started playing with fish shell today and was trying to translate a Bash function. It works but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way to pass all parameters in fish.

This is the Bash function to run Elixir command in Docker container. I used `$*` like this:

```
function elixir () {
  docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app -w /app elixir \
  sh -ci "elixir $*"
}
```

In fish, I used `$argv[1..-1]` like this:

```
function elixir --description "command to run Elixir in Docker"
  docker run --rm -it -v (pwd):/app -w /app elixir elixir $argv[1..-1]
end
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: The `[1..-1]` shouldn't be necessary, does `docker run --rm -it -v (pwd):/app -w /app elixir elixir $argv` work for you?

Comment: The functions are different: what happened to `sh -ci` in the fish version?

Comment: The ‘sh -ci’ part wasn’t exactly necessary since Docker Run was -it and —rm. Plus explicitly telling the container to start a new shell using sh -ci the container would take $argv and be like what is this $argv thing you’re throwing at me.

Comment: If I ran elixir —cookie mycookie file.exs only —cookie would be passed to the function and everything behind would be cut off, if only $argv was used.

Answer (score 8):

In fish all variables are lists, and `$var` expands to the entire list, one argument per element (so there's no word splitting or anything).

So just `$argv` is enough, there is no need to specify `[1..-1]`.

Comment: I wish it were the case but if I ran the elixir function with just $argv it would only pick up the option or flag and not anything behind it.

Comment: For example if I ran elixir —cookie mycookie file.exs only —cookie would be passed to the function and everything behind would be cut off, if only $argv was used.

Comment: That's... not what is supposed to happen. If you define a function like `function check; printf '%s\n' $argv; end`, that'll print a newline between its arguments (i.e. one argument per line if the argument does not contain a newline itself), what does `check --cookie --mycookie file.exs` print?

Comment: I think it’s tricky because the Elixir Docker image runs on Bash, so after the image name, it’s feeding commands into the image that is Bash. That was my hack around it, but I wasn’t sure if there was another preferred method.

Comment: That does not matter. `$argv[1..-1]` and `$argv` should be the exact same thing to fish, and should hence result in the exact same thing. Either there's something we're missing here or your fish has a bug. Which version is it?

Comment: fish --version
fish, version 2.7.1